# What defines a "peer", in context of review of an edit to someone else's answer?

Tags: support

What defines a "peer", in context of  review of an edit to someone else's answer?

On this site sometimes we see a message that an edit to someone else's answer will be subject to peer review.

Is a peer someone with a similar reputation to me, or someone with a huge reputation, or something in between?  Just curious.

What do one have to do to become a peer and help review other people's edits?  Just curious.  Thanks.

Comment: Please consider having a look at the [help](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help) pages, these kind of questions are already answered there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any user with enough reputation so that they have unlocked the appropriate [privilege](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/privileges).